# Can you write to a JSON file from a heroku app deployed on GitHub

Tags: json, node.js, heroku, github

I am deploying a node.js app on Heroku through GitHub and I want to write to/update a JSON file that is in the GitHub repository.  Is that possible and if so how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

No, and it's not really a recommended pattern. What are you trying to achieve? Generally it's a bad practice to mix your plumbing (code in your repo) and what runs through it (the data your app uses and creates)

A database is generally used to store and retrieve data.

Comment: I figured it out.  Thank you.

Comment: Would you be able to tell me how you figured it out, or what you did to solve your problem, I am having the same issue!